# Passing props to attributes react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, template-literals

```
const [mode_,setmode]=useState("dark")
<NavBar title="TextUtils" about="About TextUtils" mode={mode_} />
```

the code below is not working, when i console.log(props.mode) it outputs required string but there is no change in the Navbar component
when i view it from the browser
its `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand=lg navbar-${props.mode} bg-${props.mode}">`
instead of `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand=lg navbar-dark bg-dark">`

//Inside NavBar

```
<nav className={'navbar navbar-expand=lg navbar-${props.mode} bg-${props.mode}'} >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a template literal instead of a string literal, i.e. "`" instead of "'".

```js
const props = { mode: "dark" };

console.log('navbar navbar-expand=lg navbar-${props.mode} bg-${props.mode}');
console.log(`navbar navbar-expand=lg navbar-${props.mode} bg-${props.mode}`)
```

Code:

```
<nav className={`navbar navbar-expand=lg navbar-${props.mode} bg-${props.mode}`}>
```